# Angular Router Breadcrumbs with Lazy Loaded Modules

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, lazy-loading, breadcrumbs

I am working with using the Angular router to dynamically add breadcrumbs. I have followed several examples and have gotten them to successfully work.

However, if I attempt incorporate a lazy-loaded module, I get the error:

```
Root segment cannot have matrix parameters
```

I have researched that issue and have not been able to find satisfactory information/fixes.

I've created a plunk with what I am trying to accomplish to save from extensive amounts of code on this page: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/505x2r

How can I continuing utilizing the dynamic breadcrumb creation from the router, but use lazy-loaded routes as well.

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import { RootComponent } from 'src/root/root.component';
import { IndexComponent } from 'src/index/index.component';
import { SignupComponent } from 'src/signup/signup.component';
import { SigninComponent } from 'src/signin/signin.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild([
            {
            path: '',
            component: RootComponent,
            children: [
                {
                    path: 'signin',
                    loadChildren: 'src/signin/signin.module#SigninModule'
                },
                {
                    path: 'signup',
                    component: SignupComponent,
                    data: {
                        breadcrumb: 'Sign Up'
                    }
                },
                {
                    path: '',
                    component: IndexComponent
                }
            ]
        }
    ])
],
exports: [
    RouterModule
]
})
export class RootRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: https://github.com/gmostert/ng2-breadcrumb try this package

Comment: in `signin-routing.module.ts` : changing the empty path to a redirect makes it work without breaking : `{
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'signin',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },`, but the route name is doubled : `/#/signin/signin`

Comment: Check the changes I made. It is still not correct, but I could track the issue and from there you can go on: https://plnkr.co/edit/KTE39A?p=preview

Do not copy and paste this code from the plunker as I changed a few things, just take a loot at the `html` of the breadcrumb. I removed the router link. You'' have to find a way to fix you router link issue with async mode.

Comment: I made this one a bit better: https://plnkr.co/edit/aOCxS2?p=preview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you to Robert, Alex Beugnet, and DAG for their comments and getting me on the right track to a solid solution!

The final plunk is here: https://plnkr.co/edit/iedQjH?p=preview

Here are the condensed issues I ran into:

First, I had lazy loaded routes where I had data on the route in the form of breadcrumb.  When running through getBreadcrumbs, the breadcrumb label would show twice.  I resolved this by adding the following lines:

```
  if (
    child.snapshot.url.map(segment => segment.path).length === 0
  ) {
      return this.getBreadcrumbs(child, url, breadcrumbs);
  }
```

Second, I had routes that were simply a parameter input, but I needed to have it listed on the breadcrumb trail.  This was resolved by mapping the child.snapshot.url and assigning the segment to the label.

```
const routeArray = child.snapshot.url.map(segment => segment.path);
for ( let i = 0; i < routeArray.length; i++ ) {
    label = routeArray[i];
}
```

Third, I needed to show the parameter as well as the label for next route whether it was loaded immediately or lazy loaded via a module. I also ran into the following paths which needed to be split and labels assigned appropriately:

```
{
    path: ':id/products',
    loadChildren: 'src/products/products.module#ProductsModule',
    data: {
      breadcrumb: 'Products'
    }
}
```

and

```
                {
                  path: 'orders/:id',
                  component: OrderComponent,
                  data: {
                    breadcrumb: 'Orders'
                  }
                },
```

The solution to both was:

```
  for ( let i = 0; i < routeArray.length; i++ ) {
    if ( Object.keys(child.snapshot.params).length > 0 ) {
      if ( this.isParam(child.snapshot.params, routeArray[i]) ) {
        label = routeArray[i];
      } else {
        label = child.snapshot.data[ROUTE_DATA_BREADCRUMB];
      }
    } else {
      label = child.snapshot.data[ROUTE_DATA_BREADCRUMB];
    }
    const routeURL = routeArray[i];
    url += `/${routeURL}`;
    const breadcrumb: BreadCrumb = {
      label: label,
      params: child.snapshot.params,
      url: url
    };
    breadcrumbs.push(breadcrumb);
  }

private isParam(params: Params, segment: string) {
  for ( const key of Object.keys(params)) {
    const value = params[key];
    if ( value === segment ) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

With all good things, there one catch: **YOU HAVE TO HAVE A ROUTE FOR EACH PARAMETER**.

For example, if you have url: #/quotes/123456/products/123456/Generic/Tissue, you will need the following routes:

```
{
  path: ':id',
  component: ProductComponent,
  data: 'data'
},
{
  path: ':id/:make',
  component: ProductComponent,
  data: 'data'
},
{
  path: ':id/:make/:model',
  component: ProductComponent,
  data: 'data'
}
```

And you will end up with a clickable breadcrumbs that looks like this:

Home / Quotes / 123456 / Product / 123456 / Generic / Tissue

The project I am working on will only requires me to have one parameter... ever.

In the end, I am able to handle both routes loaded immediately and lazy-loaded routes which was my end-goal.  I am sure there are some instances that I have not accounted for, but I feel it's pretty solid.

Regardless, I encourage folks to take what's here and run with it.  Shoot me a note with any updates so I can what else this can become! Thx!

Comment: I trying to apply this answer but what if i want my routes to be Home/Quotes/Quote.. i don't want to show the id but replaced with another descriptive text - what shall i do? Also if i don't want to show the last breadcrumb how / where can i alter the code for that?

Comment: this example is working fine for me but i have lazy loading module and i want to display breadcrumbs after login that is from home page.when i login breadcrumbs is displaying fine but after i refresh page breadcrumbs is not appear then i have load component by routing page , what should i do to display breadcrumbs on refresh??

Comment: @CodersCreed , if you have stackblitz demo, kindly share it. thx

Answer (score 0):

I spotted several elements that are involved with the issue, and got it to 'seemingly' work :

- Your method `getBreadcrumbs()` gets called **3** times on a single navigation, which is a problem. Just add a `console.log('I pass !');` at the start of the function to see it.
- The main issue I believe is that you used a path for the lazy-loaded module. And for your breadcrumb component, it will use the empty path from your `SignUpModule`. This is what breaks because your breadcrumb component will use the path from your current activated route which is empty (''), and will effectively break the routing because you concat `/` with nothing. Changing this part in your component will make it work for the first time, as the routing to the lazy-loaded module path will be signup, and it will be able to register a routerLink that is not empty.

**breadcrumb.component.ts**

```
   let routeURL = child.snapshot.url.map(segment => segment.path).join('/');
   if(routeURL.length == 0) {
     routeURL = 'toto';
   }
   url += `/${routeURL}`;
```

- You should therefore find a way to use an empty route for your lazy-loaded module, so that the `/signup` path is for your signup component in his module. The route will be able to register correctly.